# Are there works on function complexity classes not included in FNP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Is there a sort of polynomial hierarchy in the case of function problems?

Comment: The question is too broad. What do you exactly want to know about function classes?

Comment: Sorry for being too broad at first. I wanted to know what good source of information I could find on this topic, as I will probably want to know more soon. As a reference for understanding the message from @Kaveh above, my original question was: Are there book chapters on classes of function problems not contained in FNP? If not, are there research articles on this topic?